# Direction of Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I am binding to the re-size of the browser, like so:

```
$(window).resize(function (e) { /* do stuff */ });
```

Is there a way, using `e`, to determine whether the window was re-sized Vertically or Horizontally, or both?  If I could determine the width and height beforehand I could to it, but I don't see how to do that with the event data.

I suppose I could keep 2 variables and compare/change them as the window is re-sized - but I am hoping there is a way that I can avoid that and just get that data from the event.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? However the only thing you can do is edit the event. jQuery does that sometimes too so there's a function for that. Have a look at `$.event`

Comment: I just don't want to have variables living in my code for this, if I don't have to.  If there was a way to do it without keeping 2 global variables that I have to maintain - that would be ideal.  If there is no alternative I will.

Comment: I will check out $.event as well.

Comment: You could use $(window).data() to store the values, but that's essentially the same thing, you wouldn't have extra vars in  your code...which would be shorter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfect suggestion Likwid_T! `$(window).data()` is perfect for this.

So you can do it [without](http://jsfiddle.net/4SP7M/) $.event:

```
$(window).data("old", {width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data("old").width + " - " + $(this).width());
    console.log($(this).data("old").height + " - " + $(this).height());
    $(window).data("old", {width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height()});
});​
```

Or [with](http://jsfiddle.net/4SP7M/1/) $.event:

```
$(window).data("old", {width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
$.event.add(window, "resize", function(e) {
    e.old = {};
    e.old.width = $(window).data("old").width;
    e.old.height = $(window).data("old").height;
    $(window).data("old", {width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
    return e;
})
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    console.log(e.old.width + " - " + $(this).width());
    console.log(e.old.height + " - " + $(this).height());
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link you can use to find the browsers window size: [google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=javascript+window+size&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Now to answer your question, use the above link to store the original browser size and compare it to the changed width and height values to see if it was a vertical, horizontal or both change.

Here's an example in jQuery:

```
var h = $(window).height(); // height
var w = $(window).width() // width

$(window).resize(function(e) {
    // check for change
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brian - I am aware I can do that ... and it appears by the first few responses I am going to have to do it that way. I was hoping there was a way I could just do it with the re-size event data (an not create more variables to maintain) however, if that's the only way, that's the way I will do it.  Thanks!!